# Why get noSuchMethodError for junit jupiter new version?

Tags: java, junit

I get this error when i upgrade new junit version with java 1.8.0_152:

```
aug. 11, 2017 9:46:07 DE org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.setSource(Lorg/junit/platform/engine/TestSource;)V
```

Previously i used the M4 version...which was ok, i can run tests.

I added these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-RC2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-RC2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
```

What can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractTestDescriptor.setSource(TestSource)` has been removed since JUnit version 5.0.0-M6. Please refer to [this commit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/commit/4e4112523dd1cd15bdb74f92a76013cdaecb8495#diff-de5b75c71b60101d14336f55d9e11898). So one of the solution is to change the version to 5.0.0-M5. To upgrade ther products version (junit-platform-runner or junit-vintage-engine or junit-platform-launcher) may solve this problem but I don't know until I see full stacktrace of NoSuchMethodError.